# Accessing a module array gives me a reference error

Tags: javascript, module-pattern, revealing-module-pattern

I am trying to understand the revealing-module pattern but when try to update or access the variables falling into errors  and  can anyone provide an example how to update/access the variables in revealing-module pattern

I get

> main.js:20 Uncaught ReferenceError: board is not defined at main.js:20

```js
var module = (function() {

  var publicVariable = "X";
  var board = new Array(9).fill(null)

  return {
    //This function can access `publicVariable` !
    changePlayer: function() {
      return (publicVariable = publicVariable === "X" ? "O" : "X")
    },
    MakeMove: function(i) {
      return (board[i] = publicVariable)
    },
    board: board

  }

})();
module.MakeMove(2)
console.log(board[2])
```

Comment: I fixed your question with a better title and formatted code and error message. Please use similar format in the future

Answer (score 1):

You are returning an object, so in order to access `board`, you'd have to do `console.log(module.board[2])`.